# Entity Framework throwing exception while loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to write my first app in Entity Framework.

In `program.cs` (where my `main()` is) I have line `ProdContext ctx = new ProdContext();`. The `prodContext.cs` is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Text;

namespace Entity_Framework
{
    class ProdContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

While trying to run main I get exception at above line:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

I have fresh install of Visual Studio with C# and EF (I installed it with `install-package entityframework -version 6.1.3.0`). Why am I getting that exception?

Comment: Do you have System.Configuration in your references folder?

Comment: References folder? Sorry if it's an obvious question, program is for uni assignment and we were given little to no instructions besides "select Console Application and run `install-package entityframework -version 6.1.3.0`).

Comment: In console application, where do you add dlls?

Comment: You mean EF? Through Package Manager Console, using that `install-package` command.

Comment: In Solution Explorer, check whether you have a References folder under your project

Comment: Which application type did you create? This is common issue if you're trying to run .net core application with "old" EF. There is EF Core you must use in such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you're using .NET Core application while still trying to install .NET library. EF 6 is ".NET" specific library. With .NET Core application type for your project you will have such crash (or similar) if installing .NET EF Version:

[image]

For .NET Core applications, you should install Core version. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/

Make sure you don't have this (or similar) error in your references:

[image]